# Runtime error 438 when trying to save an image on a userform to a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Excel VBA - Runtime Error '438' Object doesn't support this.

I have created a user form with 7 textboxes and a picture box.  This all works fine including the upload of the image file.
My problem concerns uploading these data including the image from the userform to an excel sheet. Once saved the sheet is to be ordered and the cells adjusted to fit their content.

The Sub runs if data is being uploaded is from textboxes.

When I run it with one of the textboxes changed to an image box I receive the error message above.

Grateful for any advice?

This is my sub

```
Private Sub CommandSave_Click()

'Save form data to new row and clear

    Dim Worksheet As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

'Save Textboxes to Worksheet

Dim lr As Long

lr = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    ws.Cells(lr, "A").Value = Me.TextBox_1.Value
    ws.Cells(lr, "B").Value = Me.TextBox_2.Value
    ws.Cells(lr, "C").Value = Me.TextBox_1 + TextBox_2.Value
    ws.Cells(lr, "D").Value = Me.TextBox_3.Value
    ws.Cells(lr, "E").Value = Me.TextBox_4.Value
    ws.Cells(lr, "G").Value = Me.TextBox_6.Value
    ws.Cells(lr, "H").Value = Me.TextBox_7.Value
    ws.Cells(lr, "I").Value = Me.TextBox_8.Value

'Save image to Cell

Dim ShpPicture As OLEObject

With ws

    Set ShpPicture = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.Image.1", _
        Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
        Left:=.Cells(lr, "F").Left, _
        Top:=.Cells(lr, "F").Top, _
        Width:=Me.Image_1.Width, _
        Height:=Me.Image_1.Height)

End With

With ShpPicture

    .objects.PictureSizeMode = 3
    .ObjectPicture = Me.Image_1.Picture
    
End With

'Empty Textboxes

    TextBox_1.Value = ""
    TextBox_2.Value = ""
    TextBox_3.Value = ""
    TextBox_4.Value = ""
    
    TextBox_6.Value = ""
    TextBox_7.Value = ""
    TextBox_8.Value = ""


'Sort Data on Two Fields

Set SortA = ws.Range("a8:i" & lr)

Sort_Two_columns A & B
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Clearws.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A8:A" & lr), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("B8:B" & lr), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ws.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A8:I" & lr)
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With

'Resize cells to fit text
    ws.UsedRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    ws.UsedRange.EntireRow.AutoFit

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi The suggested code worked enabling me to copy the image from the user form to the worksheet.  However the image is locked and cannot be activated to delete it or move it on the sheet. Any suggestions?

Comment: If somebody has answered your question, you need to mark it as answered.

Comment: Hi Dave  How do you mark a question as answered?

Comment: Select the checkmark by the answer you think is the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should be referring to the Object property of the OleObject object...

```
With ShpPicture
    .Object.PictureSizeMode = 3
    .Object.Picture = Me.Image_1.Picture 
End With
```